# How to pass string variables as arguments in function in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I wrote a simple code for a function which takes a string and return its length:

```
let fun x = String.length x;;
```

But it's showing syntax error. Why?
If I just write `String.length x;;` it's fine but what's wrong in my function declaration?

How to pass string variable as argument to function in OCaml?

Answer (score 6):

`fun` is a reserved keyword in OCaml. You can choose another name that's not a keyword and the function will work. Here's a list of reserved keywords in OCaml: https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/lex.html#sss:keywords

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing different syntaxes here:

1. LET <ident> <ident>* = <expr>
2. FUN <ident>* -> <expr>

The "let" must be followed by the name of the function you want to create and "fun", being a reserved keyword, is not a valid name for the function. It's a keyword and not an identifyer so the syntax parser gives you an error.